# Populate SharePoint list from a web service

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, web-services

SharePoint / SharePoint Designer 2007

I have a SharePoint blog site and I need to add a company to each new post.

I created a list `Company` and a lookup column in `Posts` that uses the `Company` list.

I can now select a company from a drop down list when creating/editing a post.

What I need is to populate the `Company` list from a `Web Service`.

In SharePoint Designer I added my web service to Data Source Library and clicking on it display correctly in the Data Source Details window.

How do I connect this to my SharePoint List?

At this stage I am open to both a 1 time dump of data or something that would update it periodically.

Answer (score 1):

If it's just a one time population, get all the values and just paste them into the Datasheet view of the Company list.